# VIM One sentence per line: Separated by periods

Tags: vim

I have a plain text that I would like to place each sentence on its own line. I see some answers for Perl but I am using Vim exclusively.

Comment: Hello Johnny, and welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is currently too broad to the format this website usually accepts. Please be sure to check the [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Then, please edit your question with more specific information and show us your efforts in solving this. What defines a sentence can be ambiguous, and the solution depends on the complexity of your requirements. Please state them preferably with an example. Also, if you have found a Perl solution that works, post it. Researching about Vim regex will also help.

Comment: Also, note that sentence splitting is not just about finding periods. "Prof. dr. Jack M. Smith from S.H.I.E.L.D., i.e. a V.I.P., is visiting labs in N.Y.C., N. Carolina etc."

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: `%s/\([\.!\?]\)/\1\r/gc` and a cup of coffee

Comment: Thank you for your help. My fundamental rationale is breaking up scientific papers or science text books to annotate and edit for my own reading. Simply take a text and separate each sentence (as delimited by a period) and place it on its own newline. We are still confined to the tyranny of book publishing where it makes sense to have all the text in blocks of paragraphs...ancient typography that dates back to Gutenberg. Each sentence in a textbook or scientific paper is a discrete piece of knowledge. I don't want to read everything jumbled together...so if it turns out to be a list so be it

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the question is too unclear. I saw other questions much unclear with  answers .. so .. let me try ?

If the sentences you want to separate are in one line and the "periods" only exist to separate the line then you can try the following command to split them:

```
:%s/\./.\r/g
     ^ ^ (change the dots by the character you want if needed)
```

This will look globally in the buffer for `.`, will subsitute it with itself (hmm) , and will add a line return (`\r`).

Then you may have to remove the indentation with `:%le` to format the lines to the left.

ps: that Rkta suggestion (from comment) `%s/\([\.!\?]\)/\1\r/gc` seems working fine as well (and is maybe better?). The Amadam comment is relevant as well.

Welcome to stackoverflow. read the [stackoverflow.com/tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page may help your quest ;)

Answer (score 2):

Those answers for Perl probably used *regular expressions*, and it should be relatively easy to convert the regular expression syntax to Vim's. [`:help perl-patterns`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#perl-patterns) should provide you with clues on how the syntax differs.

I'd like to propose a different solution that employs a **recursive macro definition** and Vim's *sentences motion* ([`:help (`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%28)). First, a single replacement:

```
)hr<CR>
```

This jumps to the next sentence (`)`), then moves back to the separating whitespace (`h`), and replaces it with a newline (`r<CR>`).

To turn this into a macro that repeats itself (until some action cannot be fulfilled any longer and it aborts), first clear a macro register (e.g. `a`) and start recording: `qaqqa`. Then insert the above action, and conclude with a macro invocation `@q`. End the macro (`q`) and invoke it (`@a`). Complete macro (now using register `q`):

```
qqqqq)hr<CR>@qq@q
```

This will stop at empty lines and keep line breaks inside a sentence; you may want to `:join` all lines first. Alternatively, you can also tweak the replacement (`r<CR>`), maybe to a `c`hange command. Since you didn't mention any detailed requirements in your question, I'll leave it at that.